# Can not add the host dynamically in the host file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Following is the script(Ansible version is 2.1.0):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - createVmVars.yml

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Gathering Vm info.
      vsphere_guest:
        vcenter_hostname: "{{vcenter_hostname}}"
        username: "{{vcenter_username}}"
        password: "{{vcenter_password}}"
        guest: "{{guest_name}}"
        vmware_guest_facts: yes
      register: var

  tasks:
    - name: Setting the VM Ip address in a variable.
      set_fact:
        vm_ip: "{{var.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0]}}"

    - name: Adding a new host in inventory file.
      add_host: name = "{{vm_ip}}" groups=new_group

- hosts: new_group
  remote_user: root

  vars_files:
    - createVmVars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Copying files from local to target VM.
      copy:
        src: "{{item.source}}"
        dest: "{{item.dest}}"
        mode: 0644
      with_items: files_copy
```

The script above is finding the ip address of a vm and trying to connect to that vm using ip-address(Direct instead through vcenter server) instead of using vsphere_guest module.
I used add_host module to add a host dynamically in inventory file. but i am getting the following error right after the add_host module(Not in add_host task but after it) while executing it:

**Unexpected Exception: expected string or buffer**

full traceback using -vvvv is:

```
Unexpected Exception: expected string or buffer
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/bin/ansible-playbook", line 85, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli.run())
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/cli/playbook.py", line 150, in run
    results = pbex.run()
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 140, in run
    for batch in self._get_serialized_batches(new_play):
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 209, in _get_serialized_batches
    all_hosts = self._inventory.get_hosts(play.hosts)
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 189, in get_hosts
    hosts = self._evaluate_patterns(patterns)
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 292, in _evaluate_patterns
    that = self._match_one_pattern(p)
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 345, in _match_one_pattern
    hosts = self._enumerate_matches(expr)
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 441, in _enumerate_matches
    matching_hosts = self._match_list(group.get_hosts(), 'name', pattern)
  File "/home/shasha/devOps/ansible/lib/ansible/inventory/__init__.py", line 163, in _match_list
    if pattern.match(getattr(item, item_attr)):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: clever approach! I've run into a few issues with type errors in Ansible 2, and the trace it spits out is quite obtuse. Add a debug task before the add_host task and print out the value of "{{var.ansible_facts.hw_eth0.ipaddresses[0]}}" as well as "vm_ip". My hunch is that either that fact doesn't exist or yaml is eating quotes and trying to set the ip as a number (which I've run into in the past)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer after making few silly attempts:
The line:

```
add_host: name = "{{vm_ip}}" groups=new_group
```

Contains spaces between name and = sign and between = sign and "{{vm_ip}}" and thats why it was not working properly.Though it looks very silly and meaningless but it worked that way only.The line should be:

```
add_host: name="{{vm_ip}}" groups=new_group
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the same error but still I would suggest use the `add_host` module with `local_action`.

```
 - name: addHosts to a new group
   local_action: add_host name={{ partnerIP.stdout}} groupname=UpdatedHost
```